# PCoA (Principal *Coordinate* Analysis) in Accord.net

Tags: accord.net

I've been trying to use PCA (Principal Component Analysis) in Accord.net but am not getting the correct results for PCoA. 
Is there a way to achieve this without writing the algo myself?

```
        var pca = new PrincipalComponentAnalysis()
        {
            Method = PrincipalComponentMethod.Standardize,
            Whiten = true
        };
        MultivariateLinearRegression transform = pca.Learn(distances);
        pca.NumberOfOutputs = 2;
        double[][] output = pca.Transform(distances);
```

note that the "distances" matrix is a NxN 1-correlation matrix of N time-series I get as an input.

Comment: If you still believe you are not getting the correct outputs for PCA, please post an example of your dataset as an issue in the project's issue tracker.

Comment: Also, please note that currently the framework does not include an implementation for PCoA (multi-dimensional scaling), but feel free to also open a feature request for it.

Comment: I built a correlation matrix and fed it to the PCA algo', which gave me the MDS / PCoA results I was looking for. @Cesar